# Generifying search values in JSONObject?

Tags: java, json

I have a quite varying structure JSONObject. I am using json.simple to get values from the object like this:

```
String val1 = ((LinkedHashMap<String, String>) response.get("key1")).get("inner_key1");
String val2 = ((LinkedHashMap<String, String>) response.get("key1")).get("inner_key2");
int index1 = (int) ((ArrayList) response.get("index_key1")).get(0);
int index2 = (int) ((ArrayList) response.get("index_key2")).get(0);
int index3 = (int) ((ArrayList) response.get("index_key3")).get(0);
```

I am wondering if I can use a utility method to get these values with a better, more generic way? Also, I would like to avoid those casting too, is there any solution for that?

Comment: How do you use your JSONObject? Do you always use the same fields even though the JSONObject has varying  structure?

Comment: Can you store some type information in the json?

Comment: @YugSingh That is exactly how I am using my JSONObject as you can see on the example. The keys are always the same but the values of course are not.

Comment: @Charles No, I cannot store anything in the "response". I get this JSON from a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the keys in JSON are always the same you can create a class and specify the keys as instance varaibles. Now you can use `Jackson library's Object Mapper` to convert the `JSON string` to `JSON Object` as shown in below code.

```
public class Vehicle{
private String brand = null;
private int doors = 0;

public String getBrand() { return this.brand; }
public void   setBrand(String brand){ this.brand = brand;}

public int  getDoors() { return this.doors; }
public void setDoors (int doors) { this.doors = doors; }
}
```

Insdie the main function you can write the below code:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

String carJson =
"{ \"brand\" : \"Mercedes\", \"doors\" : 5 }";

try {
Vehicle vehicle= objectMapper.readValue(carJson, Vehicle.class);

System.out.println("car brand = " + vehicle.getBrand());
System.out.println("car doors = " + vehicle.getDoors());
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also, using `Object Mapper` way you don't need to do the cast.
You can read more about it [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/).

Answer (score 1):

You could use GSON library provided by Google to map JSON to Java.

An example,

```
public class Example {

  private String val1;
  private String val2;
  private ArrayList<int> index_key1;
  private ArrayList<int> index_key2;
  private ArrayList<int> index_key3;

  ///
  //  Getter Methods
  ///

  public String getVal1() { return val1; }
  public String getVal2() { return val2; }
  public int getIndex1() { return index_key1.get(0); }
  public int getIndex2() { return index_key2.get(0); }
  public int getIndex3() { return index_key3.get(0); }
}
```

Then

```
  Example ex = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), Example .class);
```

After that you should be good to go. There also is a library called Jackson which provides a similar solution to GSON.